# C++ - Looping through vector runs infinitely

Tags: c++, loops, vector, infinite-loop, cout

I'm new to C++, came from Java (started learning yesterday).

I'm trying to loop over the elements of a vector. For some reason when I do this, it endlessly outputs empty lines.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::string expression = "5+4";
    std::vector<char> characters(expression.begin(), expression.end());
    for (char c : characters) {
        std::cout << c << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I keep running into this problem, I have no clue why it is doing this.

I tried searching if other people had this problem, but I couldn't find any questions about it or answers... what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
I'm using MinGW

GIF or it didn't happen
[image: gif]

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91c15f981f97ccbc).  Please share a [mcve] that does.

Comment: Yes @KyleKhalaf I did. This is what they said to do.

Comment: @NathanOliver What? That's literally what I am running...

Comment: Works fine for me... what compiler??

Comment: @katamarayudu I'm using MinGW

Comment: @NathanOliver I updated question

Comment: @MCMastery Thanks.  [I still cannot reproduce the issue](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b12044590c247ce8).  Maybe your installation is fubar'd.

Comment: What version of MingW are you using?  Sounds highly likely you are using an older buggy version ... I'd certainly try updating it first ...

Comment: The code is correct. Something else is going on, probably something with build is broken, i.e. you are not running this code but something else entirely (old code or something).

Comment: Double check that your cmd prompt is running in codepage `1252`. Many compilers have trouble if you use window's semi-broken utf-8 codepage called `65001`. You can ensure this by adding `chcp 152 &&` to the front of your build command. Also ensure that you build your project freshly before each run.

Comment: I have a lovely gif of a squadron of flying pigs dueling beagles on dog houses during the Great War. Glad to know that really happened.

Comment: @Aaron3468 I think you have a typo with "semi-"

Comment: @PasserBy Semi is a valid prefix in English. But I missed a "2" in `1252`.

Comment: @Aaron3468 No, you misunderstood, the word is spelled "" :)

Answer (score -3):

I'm not an expert in CPP, but i assume your code is inserting string to the vector and iterate through the vector, if so, heres the code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std; //i add this line to remove the "std" in every line
int main()
{
    string expression = "5+4";
    vector <char> characters(expression.begin(), expression.end());
    for (int i=0; i< characters.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << characters[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

An explanation that i can tell you is, you do not printing the vectors with its **index** so it'll have some bug also the looping i use i think more clear to see.

Comment: That code is valid. It is using range-based for loop (C++11). See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for